# XSLT - Select content between two special characters

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <p>text1 &lt;xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"
        standalone="yes"?&gt; text2</p>
</doc>
```

I need to remove the text content between `&lt; and &gt;` form above text using XSLT. So expected output is,

```
<doc>
    <p>text1 text2</p>
</doc>
```

I tried to use regex but I'm wondering how I can catch text between `&lt; and &gt;` form regex.

Any idea how I can do this using XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should Work.

```
(&lt;(?:.?\n?)*&gt;)
```

Then Replace with "" (empty)

Input:

```
<doc>
    <p>text1 &lt;xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"
        standalone="yes"?&gt; text2</p>
</doc>
```

Output:

```
<doc>
    <p>text1  text2</p>
</doc>
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/0o9hol/1

Answer (score 1):

Using just XSLT-1.0 you can achieve this by applying the following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="p"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before(text(), '&lt;')),' ',normalize-space(substring-after(text(), '&gt;')))" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template just copies all nodes with the *identity template* and applies a special treatment to all `<p>` elements.

The special treatment of the `<p>` nodes extracts the `text()` nodes before `&lt;` and after `&gt;` while normalizing the `space` character occurrence(reducing their count to one) and concatenates the result.

That's all.